# Ubuntu 18.04 HDMI output not recognized with Nvidia hybrid

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I can't use HDMI external display on my IdeaPad S340 with Nvidia GeForce MX230 and built-in Intel GPU.

I currently use `nvidia-driver-435 (open source)`

With my monitor plugged in i got following output:

HDMI is not listed in xrandr:

```
# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Both GPUs are detected

```
# xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1de cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x44 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 2 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

```
# dmesg | grep -i nvidia
[    3.703922] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    3.703931] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    3.710560] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    3.719549] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 234
[    3.722844] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0103)
[    3.823205] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  435.21  Sun Aug 25 08:17:57 CDT 2019
[    3.847424] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  435.21  Sun Aug 25 08:07:52 CDT 2019
[    3.849538] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    4.635389] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    4.648303] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 510.
```

Can anyone help me?

I already tried reconfiguring gdm/switching to lightdm, tried both noveau and nvidia-drivers

Comment: Please update your question with `dmesg | grep -i nvidia`

Comment: I have exactly same problem on Dell Inspiron 5593. What's also interesting is that the screen brightness adjustment does not work. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: @mactro Importunately not. Let's try with some bouty

Comment: It might be hardware. I have an Del L502x which also has an Optimus graphics system.  However, I can only use DisplayPort for the NVidia, and HDMI for the Intel.  (Or inversely, I don't remember)  It's wired like that.  From what I understand, the same problem exists under Windows.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems using nvidia cards in Laptops. Even if they work, usually suspend and hibernate won't work (reliable).. Since the performance gain using a nvidia card in a Notebook is not that large, could you try to activate the intel graphic card and check if it works? (you may have to blacklist your nvidia drivers)

Comment: It's not working even with Nvidia disabled

Comment: any relevant in `cat /​var/log/gpu-manager.log`

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `mate-optimus` that I use to make sure that my nvidia card is active. The problem for me, is that the nvidia card is not active by default and I have to explicitly turn it on.

Previously I was using nvidia-xrun to launch a full gnome session, but since I discovered the mate-optimus, I just use the little icon that it puts in the status bar to switch on the nvidia graphics which activates my hdmi.

Its in most repos I think, but more info is here: https://github.com/ubuntu-mate/mate-optimus

Comment: I get `Prime not supported.` as output from binary

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue resolved on my laptop. I had manually downloaded drivers from the nvidia website but that wasn't the right way to do it.

Running this line

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
```

and restarting resolved it. (I also have a USB C port that worked for a second screen with HDMI adapter before I got this issue resolved)

[Ubuntu 18.04.3 cant find second monitor - Dell G3 - NVIDIA 1060 TI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194131/ubuntu-18-04-3-cant-find-second-monitor-dell-g3-nvidia-1060-ti)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by disabling SecureBoot in BIOS settings. To do so follow this steps:

1. while booting enter BIOS by pressing `F2` key
2. navigate with arrow keys to `Security` tab then disable SecureBoot
3. save by pressing F10. Your PC should restart and HDMI should be working now.

Following those steps on my machine fixed the problem