# Ubuntu 19.10 not detecting HDMI cable

Tags: nvidia, sound, video, hdmi, nvidia-geforce

I have an ASUS TUF FX505DT and everything works fine in Ubuntu 19.10, except for the HDMI connection. The cable and TV worked fine when I tried them with another laptop with Linux. I'm not sure what the problem could be aside from drivers maybe. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's some system info:

[image: systeminfo]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to the NVIDIA graphics card. There are lots of posts discussing this problem with lots of different proposed solutions, but what worked for me was updating the drivers. I originally tried updating the drivers by downloading them from the NVIDIA website, but the solution was this line of code to update the drivers. You should check the NVIDIA website just to get the driver number (might vary per device). Also, prior to this fix, the HDMI was not found on my computer, but I could use the USB-C and an adapter to connect to another monitor.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435
```

[Ubuntu 18.04.3 cant find second monitor - Dell G3 - NVIDIA 1060 TI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194131/ubuntu-18-04-3-cant-find-second-monitor-dell-g3-nvidia-1060-ti)

Here's a list of other fixes people have proposed.

[External monitor not detected on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033785/external-monitor-not-detected-on-ubuntu-18-04/1194142#1194142)