# Ubuntu 18.04.3 cant find second monitor via HDMI - My labtop is Dell G3 - NVIDIA 1060 TI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a new Dell G3 laptop with an NVIDIA 1060 TI gpu. This system is set up for dual boot with windows/ubuntu. Ubuntu can't detect the HDMI port and doesn't show my second monitor. However, it works well with windows.

I've tried installing all of the routine updates. None of these things fix the problem.

I also recently change my driver with this commnad:

> sudo apt install nvidia-driver-435

but it didn't solve the problem.

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 2191 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0949
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1aeb (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1193532/1021642

TL;DR its probable that the nvidia card is not turned on. This is definitely the case for my Dell Inspiron and my wife's G3. The HDMI cable is controlled solely by the NVIDIA card

Look into mate-optimus